# jquery ajax code is working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to display a pop up after clicking add to cart button but its not working on first click when i click on second time its working and its not updating cart count
here is my html code for button

```
<INPUT type='button' class='btn-BuyOff btn-itemlist-cart'  id='addtocart'  
name='addtocart' onkeypress="window.event.cancelBubble=true;"  
onclick="show_alert<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>()">
```

This is the script which suppose to display a pop up and update the cart count. Its displaying the message that item added to cart but not updating the cart count and also working when i click on cart button second time in first click its not working

```
function show_alert<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>() {
$('.btn-itemlist-cart').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).onclick = null;

    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $($(this).get(0).form);
        var _this = $(this);

        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
            var message = $('<h3 style="color: #00a;">Added to Cart.</h3>');
            _this.before(message);
            message.fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);

            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=3713628_SB2&n=2',
                success: function(data) {
                    var newCount = parseInt(data.replace("document.write('", ''));
                    $('.cartcounter').html(newCount);
                }
            });

        }, 'html');
    });

});
}
```

it is where i suppose to update cart count.getcartcount will get the count of items.

```
<div class="cartcounter"><getcartcount></div>
```

Comment: Try reducing your code to just the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Also, look into proper event handling (no `.each()` is needed), event delegation, and using arguments or event data instead of creating functions with generated names.

Comment: .each() because there are mutiple items having same cart button

Comment: That doesn't mean you need `.each()`. Just use `$(this)` in the event handler to get the button that triggered it.

Comment: That's really some bad nesting you are doing here. with every call of your function, a click event will be bound to each cart element, for example. so you will have multiple click events on each click very soon. plus: why do you nest an `$.ajax` function inside a `$post` function?

Comment: so i dont need to use .each(). is it causing it to work this script on second click?

Comment: Im new to ajax just in learning phase trying to get it working